# Using web scraping to check if an item is in stock

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am creating a Python program that uses web scraping to check if an item is in stock. The code is a Python 3.9 script, using Beautiful Soup 4 and requests to scrape for the item's availability. I would eventually like to make the program search multiple websites and multiple links within each site so I don't have to have a bunch of scripts running at once. The expected result of the program is this:
`200`
`0`
`In Stock`
But I am getting:
`200`
`[]`
`Out Of Stock`

The '200' represents if the code can access the server, 200 is the expected result. The '0' is a boolean to see if the item is in stock, the expected response is either '0' for In Stock. I have given it both in-stock items and out of stock items and they both give the same response of `200 [] Out Of Stock`. I have a feeling there is something wrong with the `out_of_stock_divs` within the `def check_item_in_stock` because that's where I am getting the `[]` result of it finding the availability of the item

I had the code working correctly earlier yesterday, and I kept adding features (like it scraping multiple links and different websites) and that broke it, and I can't get it back to a working condition

Here's the program code. (I did base this code off of Mr. Arya Boudaie's code on his website, https://aryaboudaie.com/ I got rid of his text notifications though because I plan on just having this running on a spare computer next to me and have it play a loud sound, that will later be implemented.)

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_page_html(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(page.status_code)
    return page.content


def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_divs = soup.findAll("text", {"class": "product-inventory"})
    print(out_of_stock_divs)
    return len(out_of_stock_divs) != 0

def check_inventory():
    url = "https://www.newegg.com/hp-prodesk-400-g5-nettop-computer/p/N82E16883997492?Item=9SIA7ABC996974"
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
    if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
        print("In stock")
    else:
        print("Out of stock")

while True:
    check_inventory()
    time.sleep(60)```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product inventory status is located inside a `<div>` tag, not a `<text>` tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page_html(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(page.status_code)
    return page.content


def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-inventory"})  # <--- change "text" to div
    print(out_of_stock_divs)
    return len(out_of_stock_divs) != 0

def check_inventory():
    url = "https://www.newegg.com/hp-prodesk-400-g5-nettop-computer/p/N82E16883997492?Item=9SIA7ABC996974"
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
    if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
        print("In stock")
    else:
        print("Out of stock")

check_inventory()
```

Prints:

```
200
[<div class="product-inventory"><strong>In stock.</strong></div>]
In stock
```

---

Note: The HTML markup of that site probably changed in the past, I'd modify the `check_item_in_stock` function:

```
def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "product-inventory"})
    return out_of_stock_div.text == "In stock."
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it here soon. I was wondering why Mr. Boudaie had ```return out_of_stock_div != 0, and I was most likely going to change that to something more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve the legwork in a very readable and slightly more elegant manner with the `lxml` library:

```
import config
import requests
from lxml import html

def in_stock(url: str = config.upstream_url) -> tuple:
    """ Check the website for stock status """
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': config.user_agent})
    proc_html = html.fromstring(page.text)
    checkout_button = proc_html.get_element_by_id('addToCart')
    return (page.status, not ('disabled' in checkout_button.attrib['class']))
```

I would suggest using xpath to identify the element on the page that you want to examine. This makes it [Easy to Change](https://dzone.com/articles/the-pragmatic-programmer-an-interview-with-andy-hu) in the event of a upstream website update (outside of your control) as you only need to adjust the xpath string to reflect the upstream change:

```
# change me, if upstream web content changes
xpath_selector = r'''///button[@id='addToCart']'''
checkout_button = proc_html.xpath(xpath_selector)[0]
```

On a side note, stylistically, some purists would suggest avoiding side effects when writing functions (i.e. use of `print()` within a function). You can return a tuple with the status code and the result. This is a really nice feature in Python.

Comment: Okay! I'll have to give that a shot!

Comment: If you are running Firefox, it's really easy to find the XPath for an element. Right click on the element, select *Inspect*. In the Developer Tools (Inspector), right click on the HTML tag of interest, * Copy->XPath * You may need to edit it a bit but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know this already but Git is your friend.  Whenever you make a change push it to github or wherever you choose to save it.  Others can clone it and they will have the code you wrote so it is retrievable in multiple places if it is cloned more than once.